# How do I change a date's format in a text file?

Tags: ruby, regex, file-io

I have a text file in the format of:

```
04-01-2010 13:25
Lorem Ipsum...
03-28-2010 15:21
Lorem Ipsum...
```

etc.

And I want to change the date format so that it looks like:

```
2010-04-01 13:25
Lorem Ipsum...
2010-03-28 15:21
Lorem Ipsum...
```

etc.

The problem I'm having is I can't pass a regex directly to a proc and I'm not sure how else to do it. And the code doesn't seem to be writing to the file at all. Here is my code:

```
def dateFix(dateLine)
    dateLine = dateLine.split('-')
    newDate = dateLine.slice(2), dateLine.slice(0), dateLine.slice(1)
    newDate = newDate.join('-')
end

@reg = /\b\d\d-\d\d-\d\d\d\d\b/

File.open('some_file.txt', "r+") { |file| 
    file.each_line { |line|
        date = line if line == @reg
        if date
            file.puts line.gsub(date, dateFix(date))
        end
    }
}
```

Comment: I might use Time.parse/mktime/strftime to accomplish this -- you may wish to review [Time documentation](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Time.html)

Comment: The problem with using `parse` is it assumes a `%d-%m-%Y` format string, which is fine outside of the US, but runs afoul of our standard `%m-%d-%Y` for dates such as the second one, "03-28-2010". There is no month "28" and the parser will whine incessantly as a result..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this on:

```
require 'date'

INPUT_FILE = 'some_file.txt'
OLD_FILE   = 'some_file.old'
TEMP_FILE  = "some_file.#{ $$ }"

File.delete(OLD_FILE) if (File.exist?(OLD_FILE))

File.open(TEMP_FILE, 'w') do |fo|
  File.foreach(INPUT_FILE) do |li|
    li.chomp!
    if ( li[/^(\d{2}-\d{2}-\d{4} \S+)/] )
      fo.puts DateTime.strptime($1, '%m-%d-%Y %H:%M').strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M')
    else
      fo.puts li
    end
  end
  File.rename(INPUT_FILE, OLD_FILE)
end

File.rename(TEMP_FILE, INPUT_FILE) if (File.exist?(OLD_FILE))
```

This is more Ruby-like, and straightforward.

Be careful any time you attempt to read and write to the same file. Any crash will destroy the integrity of your file, so you're better to write to a temporary file, then rename the original when you've successfully finished reading/writing, then move the original to a safe backup, and move the new one in. That way, you still have your source, and your destination, allowing you to do triage if something goes wrong.

Comment: This worked like a charm. Thanks also for mentioning about writing to a temp file to be safe. A very useful note.

Comment: Just noticed; the very first line of the file is a date that should be changed but it appears to have been skipped and I'm not sure why.

Comment: I need more information. The code works with the sample data you gave, so what is different about the first line?

Comment: I'm really not sure what the difference is. My Sample data is the exact same structure at my real data. I thought at first it was because the day was listed with one digit instead of two, but I got the same results (no change) when I added the leading zero.

Update: I made it work by adding a leading new line by which I mean, a date/time is no longer the very first thing; there is a blank new line, and then the data.

Comment: Adding a blank line should make no difference. It will be handled by the `else` clause.

Answer (score 3):

It is tricky to read data from a file and also write to it at the same time.  I recommend reading the file a at once, closing it, then opening it for writing and writing the new contents back to it.  Be sure to make a backup in case this goes wrong.

Comment: Or this: open the file for reading, open another one for writing and start streaming and converting. No need to make a separate backup :) Also, you don't need O(N) memory.